# App crashes when my button is clicked without getting any input in text field

Tags: android

I have created my first simple currency converter app which takes INR as input and which gives amount in USD as Toast. The app works fine and returns the correct result when an amount is given as input and the "Convert" button is pressed, but as soon as no input is given and then the "Convert" button is pressed, the app crashes.

Here is the code for the `.xml` file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:fontFamily="monospace"
        android:padding="20sp"
        android:text="INR to USD converter"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:onClick="convert"
        android:text="Convert" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="29dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/currency" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/amount"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.AutoCompleteTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="34dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Amount(INR)"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And code for the main activity:

```
package com.example.asus.currencyconverter;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public void convert(View view){
        EditText amount =  (EditText) findViewById(R.id.amount);
        Double amountDouble= Double.parseDouble(amount.getText().toString());
        Double dollar= amountDouble * 0.01575;
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "$" + dollar.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main1);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace with this code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public EditText amount;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main1);
        amount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.amount);
    }

    public void convert(View view) {
        String text = amount.getText().toString();
        if (!text.isEmpty()) {
            Double amountDouble = Double.parseDouble(text);
            Double dollar = amountDouble * 0.01575;
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "$"+dollar.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please enter a valid value", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

It will show a toast to enter a value if it is empty.

Answer (score 0):

That's because when you have empty `EditText` and call `getText()` it returns empty string which you put to `Double.parseDouble()`, which raises `NumberFormatException`. You want to check first is your String is empty.

```
public void convert(View view) {
    EditText amount =  (EditText) findViewById(R.id.amount);
    String textAmount = amount.getText().toString();
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(textAmount)) {
        Double amountDouble = Double.parseDouble(textAmount);
        Double dollar= amountDouble * 0.01575;
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "$" + dollar.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```